# ApachePOI : NoClassDefFoundError : org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.invalidFormatException

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, apache-poi

I have an issue with tomcat when i want to deploy my project. The build step works fine, but during deployment it give me the following error :

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/openxml4j/exceptions/InvalidFormatException
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.getDeclaredFields(Introspection.java:110)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadFieldsAnnotation(WebAnnotationSet.java:262)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:136)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:66)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:328)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:778)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:299)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:94)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5105)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.openxml4j.exceptions.InvalidFormatException
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1291)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1119)
... 19 more
```

I imported all the libraries needed by apachepoi. Here is my libraries in buildpath :

- commons-csv-1.5.jar
- commons-fileupload-1.3.3.jar
- commons-io-2.6.jar
- easymock-3.4.jar
- gson-2.2.2.jar
- HikariCP-2.6.1.jar
- jBCrypt-0.4.jar
- jstl-1.2.jar
- log4j-1.2.17.jar
- mysql-connector-java-5.1.41-bin.jar
- objenesis-2.2.jar
- selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar
- commons-codec-1.10.jar
- commons-collections4-4.1.jar
- commons-logging-1.2.jar
- poi-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-3.17.jar
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.17.jar
- slf4j-api-1.7.22.jar
- curvesapi-1.04.jar
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar

Hope you can help me

Comment: This error typically occurs when you have a library version mismatch.

Comment: Build Path != Deployment / Runtime Path. What jars do you have at runtime? Which ones did you miss? What happens when you add them?

Comment: My librairies were not in the project.xml file, so tomcat coule not load them, even if the project was compiled... Tanks for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My librairies were not in the project.xml file, so tomcat coule not load them, even if the project was compiled... Tanks for help

Comment: You can mark your own answer as the correct one ;-)

Comment: Yeah, i had to wait a entire day before ^^

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!